# Istio: Unable to set up mutual TLS origination with an egress gateway, custom CA certificates

Tags: ssl, istio

I am having problem with configuration of mutual TLS origination with an egress gateway. I am using the configuration provided in the documentation: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination-sds/#perform-mutual-tls-origination-with-an-egress-gateway.

I am getting following error message for curl:

```
kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" -c sleep -- curl -s -v 'http://ADDRESS_HERE/Service/something'

[2021-02-05T08:14:26.529Z] "GET /Service/something HTTP/1.1" 503 UF,URX "TLS error: 100663398:public key routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECODE_ERROR 184549501:X.509 certificate routines:OPENSSL_internal:PUBLIC_KEY_DECODE_ERROR 268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" 0 333 41 - "10.240.0.214" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/11.0.10)" "3a4b121d-e232-4a89-8798-f7251e74e601" "<ADDRESS_HERE>" "<IP_ADDRESS_HERE>:9443" outbound|9443||<ADDRESS_HERE> - 10.240.0.42:9443 10.240.0.214:60150 <ADDRESS_HERE> -
```

It looks like there is an issue related to certificate but I am able to access external service with curl and the same certificate provided as the parameters of curl command. I think the isseu may be related to fact that custom certificates are not trusted by each side. Is there any way to fix it?

Here's my configuration:

Istio 1.8.0:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: externalservice-egress
spec:
  hosts:
  - api.externalservice.com
  ports:
  - number: 9443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: externalservice-egress
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 9443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - api.externalservice.com
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: externalservice-egress
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: externalservice-egress
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 9443
        tls:
          mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
          sni: api.externalservice.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: externalservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - api.externalservice.com
  gateways:
    - externalservice-egress
    - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: externalservice-egress
        port:
          number: 9443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - externalservice-egress
      port: 9443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api.externalservice.com
        port:
          number: 9443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: externalservice-egress-tls-origination
  namespace: istio-system # namespace other than for other configuration items - like for example from documentation
spec:
  host: api.externalservice.com
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 9443
      tls:
        mode: MUTUAL
        credentialName: client-credential
        sni: api.externalservice.com
```

Kubernetes secret:

```
kubectl describe secret -n istio-system client-credential 

Name:         client-credential
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
tls.key:  1679 bytes
ca.crt:   1525 bytes
tls.crt:  1956 bytes
```

api.externalservice.com is an external service listening only on https/9443.

I believe that client.crt, client.key and ca.crt used for creating this secret are correct because I could connect to api.externalservice.com from outside the mesh:

```
curl -k --cert client.crt --key client.key -v https://ADDRESS_HERE:9443/Service/something
```

Thank you for helping me with this. I appreciate any ideas how to resolve this issue.

EDIT: OK, it looks like I need to provide ca cartificate somewhere:

```
Error [IST0129] (DestinationRule rule) DestinationRule namespace/rule in namespace namespace has TLS mode set to MUTUAL but no caCertificates are set to validate server identity for host: <ADDRESS_HERE> at port number:9443
```

I am using Egress Gateway, so should I mount this certificate to the Egress GW pod?

EDIT2: Also, I was under the impression that certificate management is handled by client-credential secret. Is it really needed to also add caCertificates parameter?

Comment: As to the last error message, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25652) on GitHub, which seems related.

Comment: Thanks, @mario. Could you confirm if ca.crt in client-credential should point to server's CA certifiacte or client's CA cert?

Comment: Hello @FlashGordon, 3 things that I would like to point out: 1. As to CA cert, when you set a mutual TLS, it is common for both server and client. So it should be only one CA cert. 2. What exactly do you put in plase of `"ADDRESS_HERE"` ? Is it a `domain` address, for which `common name` is set in your certificate or is it IP address ? 3. I have some doubs as to your way of verifying your configuration, namely `curl` with `-k` option i.e. `--insecure`, which `allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers"`, your CA cert is not verified and it doesn't confirm setup is correct.